# Laravel 5.3 Cannot Find File Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've setup a project more than a month ago and all of a sudden (this afternoon) I started getting the following error:

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/project/api/storage/framework/cache/d8/00/d800874b5dc22b961e0ee92f8d1c5a09c24ee911): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I've done research and tried the following with no success:

```
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 storage (I know this is not ideal)
composer update
```

Nothing is working. Before the `chmod` I was getting a permission error. I'm tapped out of ideas. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server runs CentOS 7 and somehow Selinux was set to enforcing which breaks Laravel for some reason. I remember changing it when I first set up Laravel, but somehow it reverted back.

So setting it to permissive or disabled fixed it for me.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 0):

You gave 777 to /storage folder but did you also make sure it's in same group as apache server is running?

Generally apache is in www-data group, add storage and bootstrap folder to be written by this group:

```
chgrp -R www-data /storage /bootstrap
```

Assign current user and group permission to read and write:

```
chmod -R ug+rw /storage /bootstrap
```

I'm 99% sure this will do it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and no luck. What has me puzzled is this has been working perfectly for a month now. Out of no where this happened.

Comment: Hey can you try composer dump-autoload it seems like laravel is trying to get a file that no longer exists

Comment: I tried that a few times yesterday with no luck. It was due to Selinux set to `enforce`.